# Help with naming a variable in a linear model

Tags: variance, linear-model

I would like to model an observable $X$ as a sum of underlying signal $X^*$ and instrumental noise $\epsilon$

$$X = (1 - \alpha) X^* + \alpha \epsilon$$

Here
$$X^* \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$$
$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$$

$\sigma$ and $\alpha$ are known constants and $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

I find $\alpha$ very useful to describe my model:

- When $\alpha = 0$, I have no noise, only signal
- When $\alpha = 1$, I have only noise, no signal
- $\alpha$ interploates linearly between noise and signal
- Changing $\alpha$ keeps the variance of the observable unchanged

I would like to find a good name for $\alpha$ in my publication. The best thing that comes to my mind is Noise Fraction. Is that a good name? Is there a common name for such a variable in the literature?

Note: I am aware of existence of a related concept of signal-to-noise ratio, which is the ratio of the variances of signal and noise. I find $\alpha$ more useful for my publication for the reasons bullet-pointed above, so I would like to stick with it if possible.

Comment: This is an exceptionally limited and restrictive model.  In particular, assuming $X^{*}$ and $\epsilon$ are supposed to be uncorrelated, it precludes any possibility that the variance of $X$ could exceed $1.$  This leads me to wonder whether you have correctly written down the model you intended to use.  It also suggests that nothing like this has appeared in statistical literature.

Comment: I'm not using this model to fit data, I'm using it to simulate some random numbers that I will use later to test some statistical metrics. Sure, I'll add the variance, but the question is not really about that. You are right, I indeed have to assume statistical independence of $X$ and $\epsilon$

Comment: This random generator is equivalent to $X=X*+\varepsilon$ with $X\sim {\cal N}(0,(1-\alpha)\sigma^2)$ and $\varepsilon\sim {\cal N}(0,\alpha\sigma^2)$. In other words: only the varainces of $X*$ and $\epsilon$ are different, but not their mean value. Is this really what you mean? Or are you trying to simulate a signal to noise ratio?

Comment: @cdalitz I don't see a difference between your two cases. Yes, it is as simple as scaling the variances of the individual variables by some number. Yes, I am trying to simulate signal to noise ratio using a related parameter, and want a good way to name it. Btw you have a typo, when bringing multipliers into the variance they should be squared AFAIK